# Binding navigation properties to formview

Tags: entity-framework-4, objectdatasource, formview

I'm using formview and objectdatasource for editing/inserting objectdatasource.
I want to update an entityobject properties together with its navigation properties in a single formview.
Is this possible? Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. One way is to override the `FormView.ItemInserting/ItemUpdating` methods and add add new values of any type and kind (including navigation properties) by hand here.

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example that shows how to add multiple values for many-to-many relationship entities ?